# Create pandas dataframe manually without columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, manual

I would like to create the following dataframe without columns names

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0,423,2342],[12,123,1231], [1,3,5])
```

I get back an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried `{}`, but it did not help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({[0,423,2342],[12,123,1231], [1,3,5]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you should pass your data as a 2D array, otherwise the constructor thinks you've passed several positional arguments.

```
DataFrame([[0,423,2342],[12,123,1231], [1,3,5]])
```

Comment: Technically, this is a list of lists.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Yes, technically it's a nested list that is isomorphic to 2D array.